# PgRouting Obtain RoadNetwork data from osm file

Tags: openstreetmap, pgrouting, osm2pgrouting

I am trying to obtain road-network data from OSM file using pgrouting and for this I am following this tutorial:

http://workshop.pgrouting.org/

The format I am looking for is following(bidirectional)

```
OSM_ID_1 OSM_ID_2 legth
OSM_ID_2 OSM_ID_1 legth
OSM_ID_3 OSM_ID_2 legth
OSM_ID_2 OSM_ID_3 legth
OSM_ID_3 OSM_ID_4 legth
OSM_ID_4 OSM_ID_3 legth
OSM_ID_2 OSM_ID_4 legth
OSM_ID_2 OSM_ID_4 legth
```

and so on...

I find that they have missing steps. At the end of this chapter they download the data in form of OSM files.
http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/installation.html

Next chapter, they are using `data` from the "workshop directory":
http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/topology.html

I have no idea how the got from one step to another.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 4):

The "Topology" chapter of the workshop is there to explain the basics about the routing network. The first paragraph should actually explain that. If it's not so clear, then I will change this with the next version of the workshop.

But if you import OSM data you just use an import tool named "osm2pgrouting", which is explained in detail a few chapters later: http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/osm2pgrouting.html